# How to change chapter name

Tags: chapters

I have created separated chapter which I then include in the main body, but I want to change the name.

The name created is something like this:

[image]

I want to create either:

Ch4: Analysis

or

IV. Analysis

How can I do that in latex?

P.S. The name in analysis file is \chapter{Analysis} and then I include this file in the main body using the following command: \include{chapters/Analysis}

Answer (score 1):

`titlesec` package is your friend.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand\mychapN{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\Huge \bfseries}{}{0pt}
{\parbox[t]{\chapnumb}{%
   \chaptername\ \thechapter\ \\[1em] ##1}%
{%
}}}

\newlength\chapnumb
\setlength\chapnumb{\linewidth}
\newcommand\mychap{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont \Huge \bfseries}{}{0pt}
{ Ch:\thechapter\  ##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\mychapN
\chapter{Introduction}

\mychap
\chapter{Analysis}

\mychapN
\chapter{Results}

\end{document}
```

[image]